# my codes goes infinity loop and does not prompts the user anymore

Tags: java, exception, boolean, do-while

```
boolean acceptPcode=true;
boolean acceptQty=false;
int Qty=0;
List<Integer> purchasedProdQty=new ArrayList<>();

while(acceptPcode==true && acceptQty==false){
        do{
            try{
                 System.out.print("Enter Qty: ");
                    Qty=sc.nextInt();
                    acceptQty=true;                 
              }catch(InputMismatchException ime){
                    System.out.println("Invalid quantity please enter a number!");
                    acceptQty=false;
              }

                    if(acceptQty==true)
                    purchaseProdQty.add(Qty);

           }while(acceptQty==false);

}
```

my question is that when i enter a letter it goes in an infinity loop and it doesn't prompt the user to enter a quantity ....which is

Enter Qty: Invalid quantity please enter a number!

Enter Qty: Invalid quantity please enter a number!

Enter Qty: Invalid quantity please enter a number!......

Comment: Log more information about the exception you get.

Comment: @Josay. There is no exception. It's pretty clear from the question.

Comment: @Harold_Seiner What is sc?

Comment: The following question might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608990/creating-an-array-list-java/21609314#21609314

Its very similar. You loop until a condition. I feel it might be due to the lack of the <b>second</b> scanner.

Comment: @MadPhysicist `Scanner sc` maybe?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am a bit confused here. How do we get "Invalid quantity please enter a number!" if we don't have an exception to catch ?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. Possibly. The problem is pretty clearly with what sc is doing, so we need to know what it is without having to guess.

Comment: @Josay. Good point. Back to needing to know what sc is...

Comment: Given the context, isn't it blatantly obvious that `sc` is a `Scanner`!?

Comment: @MadPhysicist AFAIK `Scanner` is the only class in Java SE that has a `nextInt` method to, uhm, read `int` input.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. I do not doubt that. I am just wondering how it is initialized. Is it wrapped around `System.in`? Is it a file scanner? I hate when people make you guess to debug their code. That being said, good answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist this statement: *`System.out.print("Enter Qty: ");`* answers your last comment.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. It implies an answer, yes. But the code is still very incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to read the `\n` (or `\r\n`) characters that are from the next line. In your current code, the scanner is waiting for an `int` input, bu the current next input is this break line char. Just add `sc.nextLine()` in your code to consume the break line char:

```
Qty=sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
acceptQty=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather it seems your scanner(sc) is throwing an exception. This causes acceptQty to constantly be false keeping you stuck in your inner do-while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consume any illegal characters in the exception block otherwise they won't be consumed by the `Scanner#nextInt` method call causing the loop to repeat itself indefinitely:

```
} catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
    System.out.println
      ("Invalid quantity: " + sc.nextLine() + " please enter a number ");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exception while reading out of sc and so it always go into infinity loop. Can you paste what's the value assiged in sc?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're doing this all wrong. Your method of validation is very obscure and can be simplified. Suppose you have the following method:

```
public int readNumber(final String prompt, final Scanner scanner){
    System.out.println(prompt);
    try{
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.err.println("Enter a valid number");
        return readNumber(prompt, scanner);
    }
}
```

This method will print out the prompt (the first argument) and read input from the provided `Scanner` (the second argument). If the user enters something that can't be parsed as an `int`, it will invoke the same method (recursion).

Take out both of your loops and when you want to read an `int` from your `Scanner`, do something like:

```
int value = readNumber("Enter a quantity", sc);
```

You know for sure that `Integer.MAX_VALUE >= value >= Integer.MIN_VALUE`